Current spike through bootstrap circuitry during turn-on and off of HS FET (GaN FET half bridge dc-dc)
I am looking at the Vds overshoot behavior of Gan FETs through a half-bridge buck boost SPICE simulation. I have been varying gate resistance and parasitic inductance in the power loop. I noticed there is a large current spike through the bootstrap circuit when the HS FET turns on and off. As parasitic inductance increases the spike at HS turn-off grows considerably (upwards of 60A at 8nH inductance).
The spike which occurs at HS turn-on is shown below. My understanding is that as the HS FET turns on, current begins to be redirected from flowing through the LS FET to the HS and this change in current induces a voltage drop across the parasitic inductor "Parasitic1" which reverse biasing the bootstrap diode (it was previously forward biased) and because of the reverse recovery time current flows through the bootstrap loop until the diode stops conducting and this quick stop in current creates the oscillation shown below. Please correct my reasoning here if necessary.

On the HS turn-off event current begins flowing through the lower FET again inducing a voltage in Parasitic1; however, this time of opposite polarity thus forward biasing the bootstrap diode and allowing a large current to flow.
Is this behavior normal in bootstrapped circuits? I would appreciate any insight, thank you.
Here is my simulation circuit:


It would be more helpful if you showed a longer time-base and a few more signals, such as voltage Vg at the bottom FET and voltage VG-S (differentially) at the top FET.  I've attempted an answer, anyways.

Yes, these are typical issues in bootstrap circuits, when loose layouts and fast switching are involved.
8nH is wild large for GaN; with DFN types, that should be down in the <5nH range for the total loop, let alone per device.  You'll have to practice layout strategies to pack them as close as possible, and estimate (or build and measure) stray inductance from that to build a representative simulation model from.
You may also find it effective to add RC snubbers around.  These are problematic because they have some ESL themselves, which can only act in parallel with the stray L to reduce but not fully dampen the Q of the resonance with Coss and Cstray.  Using multiple in parallel helps, and positioned as closely as possible to the transistors.
Note that your bootstrap supply has zero impedance to [low side]*, only Parasitic1 in that loop, which shares current with the load and [high side].  This might not be entirely realistic.  But it depends on layout.
At such short time scales, SPICE's diode model likely isn't proving very realistic.  Diode recovery is a diffusive transport problem, and in general requires a field solution.  SPICE approximates it as a single-step element (a nonlinear dependent capacitor), which works well in the long-time limit, but falls apart for PN diodes in the sub-100ns range.  It may suffice to increase ESR and ESL here, and add an RC to dampen the ESL (or use an R||L to express ESR), basically to express that the diode is not, in fact, perfectly conductive for short transients, but will drop some voltage (current-dependent) corresponding to its minority carrier concentration in forward bias.  Ideally these elements would themselves be dependent, but that's hard, and tuning them for representative values under the given bias condition might suffice.
You might also want a zener diode on the bootstrap (parallel C1), so that stray inductance (Parasitic1, etc.) can't overcharge it and destroy [high side].  Note that GaN EHEMTs aren't MOSFETs as such, and they do draw some gate current; the current increases rapidly outside of the voltage rating, and destruction soon follows.
*Designators and part numbers/models are illegible at this scale.  (Why are they so small, anyway? I've seen more than several screenshots now with microscopic text in LTSpice. I strongly encourage maximum readability here.)

This is very helpful I appreciate your quick response. I am simulating large inductances because I eventually plan to use these FETs in a multilevel converter and will have to work with some significant amount of inductance. I understand 16n is huge. And definitely agree diode is not being modelled accurately. I will try your suggestions to better model the diode behavior.

See my comment for suggested improvements to your question.
My best guess is that you are seeing your 8.6uH inductor resonate against your switchnode parasitic capacitances, which you (largely) haven't drawn and thus are just intrinsic to the FETs and gate driver BJTs.
Why is this my guess? because the period of oscillation is quite large, looks on the order of 10ns and looks very undamped, at least on this timescale.
Furthermore, you show <50ns of resonance, whereas your dead time is 50ns  (assumption based on your parameter names).  This could just be the bottom-side turning off before the top-side turns on.
Can you show the switch node voltage and gate voltage waveforms? I'll update my answer then.
